# Unity3d: Random.Range() Not working the way I intended

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm spawning objects from a list and so-far i got them to find a parent object that's already live in the scene.The problem is Random.Range() isn't working like I want. I want the listed Objects to spawn to a random parent, instead, they're spawning to the they're parent relative to the order of the list.

Ex. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 = Bad
Ex. 8,3,1,4,6,3,7,9,5,2 = Good 
lol

```
var theRange = Random.Range(obj1.Length,obj1.Length);
    for(var i: int = 0; i < theRange; i++){
        var obj2 : GameObject = obj1[i];
        if(obj2.transform.childCount == 0){
        objfromList.transform.parent = obj2.transform;
        objfromList.transform.localPosition = Vector3(0,-2,0);
    }
    }
```

Deeply thankful

Comment: If `obj1.length` is say 10, your statement `Random.Range(obj1.Length,obj1.Length);` reads `Random.Range(10,10);`  So it will never return anything but 10.  Additionally Random.Range doesn't guarantee you won't see duplicates.

Comment: You're right, and I did change it to Random.Range(0,obj1.Length); and there was no difference in the way they spawned. Plus I checked if childcount was 0. Also they're only ten parents and ten children so duplicating is killed off completely. Thanks Jerdak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment, it sounds like you just want a shuffle function.  Here is a simple [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
void shuffle(int[] a){
    for(int i = a.Length-1; i>=0; i--){
        int j = Random.Range(0,i);
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}

void usage(){
    int[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5}; // assumes obj1.Length = 6
    shuffle(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++){
        GameObject obj2 = obj1[a[i]];
        GameObject objFromList = GetNextObject(); // dummy method grabbing next list object

        objFromList.transform.parent = obj2.transform;
        objFromList.transform.localPosition = Vector3(0,-2,0);
    }
}
```

This should get you part way to what you need.  If the order of `obj1` isn't important you can shuffle it directly instead of using a secondary array like `a` in my example.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know if this helps.

Comment: I just tried it and it gave me an error( Object reference not set to an instance of an object... ). Could this be because I implementing it wrong? After I put the shuffle snippet in I replaced the (var obj2 : GameObject = obj1[i];) with (var obj2 : GameObject = obj1[tmp];), oh and sorry I didn't say anything before but I'm currently using Unityscript but I have no problem converting.

Comment: It's on me for using C#.  I greatly dislike `UnityScript` so I avoid it.  I don't know what you set `tmp` to but I'd suggest debugging to make sure the value of `tmp` is in range `[0,obj1.Length-1]`.  Also note that `objFromList` needs to change every iteration of the for loop or it will only be set to the last value of the shuffled array.  You can always update your original question with all of your code, it might help to see what's been done.

Comment: I put this snippet in my regular code: I replaced the numbers in the curly brackets with the actual Length of obj1 var a: int[];
a = obj1.Length;
shuffle(a);
for(var v: int = 0; v < a.Length; v++){
 var obj2: GameObject = obj1[a[v]];
        if(obj2.transform.childCount == 0){
        objFromList .transform.parent= obj2.transform;
        objFromList .transform.localPosition = Vector3(0,-2,0);
        objFromList .transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        objFromList .transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        }
}

Comment: Then in a seperate function I added the shuffle snippet: function shuffle(a:int[]){
 for(var i:int  = a.Length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var j:int  = Random.Range(0,i);
        tmp       = a[i];
        a[i]   = a[j];
        a[j]   = tmp;
    }
}

Comment: When I tested this it only said I couldn't convert the int (obj1.Length) to int[]; which is confusing since obj1 is a list to begin with. ???

Comment: @n900orbit You are assigning the int `obj1.Length` to `var a: int[]`, that won't work.  You need to [do something](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Which_Kind_Of_Array_Or_Collection_Should_I_Use?) like `var a = new int[obj1.Length]` and then manually fill `a`.

Comment: After a day of rest I was able to get this to work using this shuffle method but this solution didn't really solve this exact problem but it does help for future issues I may have. This seems redundant being that I have an object pool already. Isn't there another way than individually filling each object in because the more levels I have the more objects I'm creating? Please excuse my newbness lol

Comment: @n900orbit You can shuffle the object list directly without using `var a: int[]` if you don't care about the list's original order.  Individually won't work because `Random.Range` does not guarantee uniqueness.  It might return 3,4,1,3... and now you've assigned 2 objects to obj[3].  You could use a hash table to store previously used values but you'll end up with a lot of collisions and inefficiency in your program.